# get size of statusbar without use UIApplication.shared

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a cocoa lib, and I need to obtain statusbar height, I use this code:

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden ? CGFloat(0) : UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

i I use lib inside another project, all works fine, but if I use Lib inside an app extension, I obtain:

```
'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead
```

How can I test if I'm inside extension? or how can I get status height without use shared?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this solution:

```
extension UIViewController{


/// Calculate top distance with "navigationBar" and "statusBar" by adding a
/// subview constraint to navigationBar or to topAnchor or superview
/// - Returns: The real distance between topViewController and Bottom navigationBar
func calculateTopDistance() -> CGFloat{

    /// Create view for misure
    let misureView : UIView     = UIView()
    misureView.backgroundColor  = .clear
    view.addSubview(misureView)

    /// Add needed constraint
    misureView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints                    = false
    misureView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive     = true
    misureView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive   = true
    misureView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    if let nav = navigationController {
        misureView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nav.navigationBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }else{
        misureView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    /// Force layout
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    /// Calculate distance
    let distance = view.frame.size.height - misureView.frame.size.height

    /// Remove from superview
    misureView.removeFromSuperview()

    return distance

}

}
```

I wrote an article on medium, here:

https://medium.com/@lucabecchetti/calculate-top-distance-status-bar-height-and-navigation-bar-height-of-uiviewcontroller-without-e4dbfe241a77

Comment: It's doesn't work for me, always return 0 in shared extension

Answer (score 1):

Use your view controller's `topLayoutGuide.length`, or your view controller's view's `safeAreaInsets.top` if you're targeting iOS 11. These values will take into account any navigation bars as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
let statusBarHeight = Util.statusBarHeight()

class Util: NSObject {
    class func statusBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden ? CGFloat(0) : 
         UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
   }
}
```

I always follow the above approach to access global UI elements, like orientation, status bar height etc.

Comment: If we are in extension we can't use UIApplication.shared inside the code or it not compile! We can use it always if there is a #if SOMETHING #endif